# PHP 8.1 DateTime Diff returns wrong result using different Timezones

Tags: php

I need to calc the years between two dates. When one of the dates are in UTC I get a negative value for year. In this case I get -30. It should be +29. Anyone had the same problem?
This happens only as of PHP 8.1.10

```
$startDate = new \DateTimeImmutable('1993-06-05 00:00:00', new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$endDate = new \DateTimeImmutable('2023-01-02 00:00:00', new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));

var_dump($startDate->diff($endDate));
```

```
object(DateInterval)#3 (16) {
  ["y"]=>
  int(-30)
}
```

[Online Demo](https://3v4l.org/1ni1O)

Comment: Indeed. See [PHP 8.1.10 change logs](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-8.php#8.1.10), and this [bugfix](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=81263) and [this one](https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/8730).

Comment: `intval($dateTime->diff($date)->days/365)` output `int(29)` (https://3v4l.org/nRqD0#v8.2.0)

Comment: As I understood 8.1.10 fixed the examples postet in the bugfix but broke my example.
Your workaround seems to work. THX